# SimpleActionClient callback for pre-empted goals

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given a simple action client and server pair, working in callback mode, I dont think it's possible to get the client to be aware of when goals are pre-empted. It would seem a fairly 'simple' thing to want to be aware of. Goals when they're preempted in the server, trigger the server's callback, but once you're inside that callback nothing can get through to the action client's callbacks (not setSucceeded, setFeedback or setCanceled). Nothing turns up at the client's end I think because it is triggering on transitions, and it isn't set up for these particular transitions.

Or is there a way to do this that I've missed? Right now I'm looking at having to set up a specific subscriber to the action server's result topic, which works around the client/server mechanisms. Either that or go the full action server. A bit overkill for what I'm trying.

I wrote a simplified package to demonstrate. To compile, download the [tarball](http://snorriheim.dnsdojo.com/tmp/action_cb_tutorial.tar.gz), or just to view the source:

- [server.cpp](http://snorriheim.dnsdojo.com/tmp/action_cb_tutorial/src/server.cpp)
- [client.cpp](http://snorriheim.dnsdojo.com/tmp/action_cb_tutorial/src/client.cpp)

Is there something awry in the server handling?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9997/simpleactionclient-callback-for-pre-empted-goals/) by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3170 on 2011-05-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-06-23**:
Tried a simple server/full client with callbacks. It gave full feedback on current/past goals with a callback that could act on any transition. I'd recommend not being shy to go past the simple server/simple client pair if you need some extra functionality as it is also surprisingly 'simple'.

**Comment by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on 2021-03-24**:
I know this was a long time ago, but any chance you could repost your code? I think it'll be very helpful for something I'm trying to put together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Daniel,

After running your `client` and `server` programs (and triggering the counting on the `/update` topic), it looks like the `doneCallback` is being triggered correctly upon successful goal completion.

However, you are concerned about the fact that the `doneCallback` is not being triggered upon goal preemption.  Your `server` app is actually dealing with the preemption correctly.  However, it is the client which is ignoring the pre-emption.  This is not a bug.  As soon as you send a new goal with the `SimpleActionClient`, it disables the callbacks associated with the previous goal. Thus, you never hear about when the old goal got preempted.

This behavior is described deep in the actionlib docs at:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib/DetailedDescription#Simple_Action_Client

---

Originally posted by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) with karma: 760 on 2011-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-05-25**:
Of course! I just tried running the client twice in parallel (which is partially my use case) and it successfully calls the done callback on a goal pre-empted by a goal sent by another process. I feel a bit naive now :P Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Preemption should trigger the done callback that you can pass to SimpleActionClient::sendGoal. In case of preemption, the callback gets a SimpleClientGoalState set to preempted. If that doesn't work for you, I suspect there is something wrong in the server. Did you try implementing it using the execute callback instead of using a goal and a preemption callback?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-05-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Daniel,

Assuming you registered a `SimpleDoneCallback()` when you call `SimpleActionClient::sendGoal()`, you should most definitely receive a callback when the goal goes into a `PREEMPTED` state on the server.  However, I think you might be using the action server slightly incorrectly.

Please refer to the following state transition diagram, copied from [actionlib/DetailedDescription](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib/DetailedDescription):
[image: Server States Detailed]

When someone cancels a goal, the server does not immediately transition into a `PREEMPTED` or `RECALLED` state. Instead, the goal goes to either `RECALLING` or `PREEMPTING`, and the action server's cancel callback is called.  It is then the server implementer's responsibility to transition the goal into a terminal state by calling `setCancelled()`, `setAborted()`, or `setSucceeded()`.  As soon as the goal is transitioned into a terminal state, the client's `SimpleDoneCallback` will get triggered.

---

Originally posted by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) with karma: 760 on 2011-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-05-22**:
Ok, I'll see if I can revisit things and induce my current state of affairs in a simple example and see where that gets me, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I can see, the server cancels your goal correctly. I see a result message on the result topic and the goal transitions to state PREEMPTED on the status topic. The problem lies in the client. You do not explicitly cancel the goal but just send another one. One implication of this is that the client stops tracking the old goal before the preemption could be received and starts tracking the new goal. If you explicitly cancel the goal and wait for a result before sending the new goal, the client's done callback is executed with status preempted.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-05-25**:
Yep - rewriting our joint trajectory controller/action servers tomorrow - thank you for the feedback!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-05-25**:
I think not using SimpleActionClient but the more complex ActionClient might work for you. It allows you to specify per-goal callbacks and isn't too hard to use either.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-05-25**:
I hoped to avoid pre-emption management in the client (seems a bit redundant in both server and client?), but more importantly, we want to handle both cancelling and merging of goals differently in the server.  Explicitly cancelling from the client doesn't allow for that. Need to rethink our design.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-05-25**:
I was going to mention the constructor defaults to startup with a spin thread but vpradeep beat me to it.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-05-24**:
You are right, Vijay. I've updated my answer. It was not terminating on the computer I tried out the program first though. No idea why.

**Comment by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on 2011-05-24**:
waitForServer should actually terminate.  When he constructs the action client, it defaults to starting it's own spin thread, which means that waitForServer will actually get the necessary callbacks to unblock.